# How to pass named variables to a function in tupled form Python

Tags: python, syntax

I have a class with a method:

```
class Learner:
    def fit(x,y,iterations=1,subsample_proportion=0.1):
         etc...
    def predict(X):
         etc..
```

And a function:

```
def error(learner,learner_args,X,Y):
     learner.fit(learner_args)
     Y_pred = learner.predict(X)
     etc...
```

How do I make the `learner_args` tuple to pass into this function in Python?

Right now I have:

```
learner = ada_boost.AdaBoost
learner_args = (train_x,train_y,4,0.2)
```

And it doesn't work.

Also, is there a way to pass named parameters to a function call?

so, for instance, in my function, I would do:

```
learner_args = (train_x,train_y,subsample_proportion=0.2)
```

Ignoring iterations.  Is there a way to do this in Python? (internal to the language...not by using a dictionary and testing for values everywhere)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `**` before a dictionary. Example:

```
def f(a,b, c=0, d='a'):
    print a,b,c,d

kwargs = {'a' = 1, 'b' = 2}
f(**kwargs)
>>> 1 2 0 a
```

edit:

According to your comments, you might want something like:

```
args = ('first argument', 'second argument')
kwargs = {'c':'named argument c', 'd':'named argument d'}
f(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 'first argument', 'second argument', 'named argument c', 'named argument d'
```

Comment: I think it does; I just have to do: `learner_args = (args,kwargs)` and, when I pass it, do `learner.fit(*learner_args[0],**learner_args[1])`

Comment: Actually, it works either way: if i name everything, or tuple the positional params, and dict the named ones.

Answer (score 1):

`learner_args` is fine; you just need to pass it properly.

```
learner.fit(*learner_args)
```

Comment: Ah, awesome.  And is there a way to pass the named parameters?

Comment: @bordeo: Use `**` with a dictionary.  `**kwargs` for example.